# Angle brackets in PHP string

Tags: php, string, variables, brackets

It keeps killing me for some time...

I'm new to php and I'm writing a parser for price comparison site, therefore I need to have quite a few variables:

```
$plae = "<pastwisko>";
$user = "<krowa>";
$product "<trawa>";
```

But without spaces...

Using or echoing those gives me nothing. I've tried to search stackoverflow, google and php documentation and nothing... maybe my english sucks...

Thou I'll be really greatfull for help

Comment: Are you new to HTML too?

Comment: No, most certainly not :) I just probably didn't figure out all dependencies of html within php

Comment: There are no such dependencies. PHP has absolutely nothing to do with HTML.

Answer (score 4):

If you are echoing those into HTML then they will be parsed as [incorrect] HTML tags by your browser and will not show. You should use `htmlentities` to make them display as text: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot a "=".

```
$product "<trawa>";
// Should be.
$product = "<trawa>";
```

Edit:
Joe has the correct answer to your problem, I ran the script in the terminal and that was the only error I was given. I didn't think of `htmlentities`, I'm sorry if my post was irrelevant and unnecessary.

Comment: My bad, that was just an example :) Thx!